# How do I make a redirectAction when using REST Plugin (Struts 2)

Tags: plugins, redirect, struts2, redirecttoaction

Considering the typical case when, after creating, updating or deleting an element, you want to do a redirectAction to the "index" action (or whatever other action). ¿How do you make it if you are using the REST Plugin?

Comment: Is it that I made the wrong question? Or is it that I'm supposed to add some "code to be fixed"? What's up nobody answered? (Anyway, thanks for reading!)

Answer (score 2):

In your action, you can do: `return "index"` and before declaring your class, you can use the Results annotation. For example:

```
@Results({
    @Result(name="create", location="/home", type="redirect")
})
```

or

```
@Results({
    @Result(name="success", type="redirectAction", params = {"actionName" , "orders"})
})
```

Hope it helps